# Proving $b^{33} = e.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, *)$ be a group and $a$, $b$ belongs to $G$. Suppose that $a^2 = e$ and $a*b^4*a = b^7$. Prove that $b^{33} = e$.
I dont know how to proceed.